# Can I transfer PS3 profile if I've started GTA V online on PS4?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online, ps4

I only need one solo play trophy (gold medals) and two online trophies (platinum awards and level 100) to get the platinum on PS3 for GTA V.

I only really want to do the online grind once - so I've been holding off on playing on my PS4 until I get the two online trophies (I'm level 85ish).

However - I play with a few friends who've all already moved to the PS4. Could I just start on the PS4 as a new character, and then overwrite that online profile with my PS3 profile later on?

I have a PS+ profile for the PS3.

Comment: Ps3 and Ps4 trophys are seperated, no way to merge those

Comment: My question isn't about merging trophies - I want to know if I overwrite the PS4 profile later on if I start one.

Comment: What kind of profile, local or online?

Comment: The cloud saved online profile

Comment: Ah okay now i got it.. so process you did on the ps3 are imported on the ps4 and trophys you got in gta-online are also imported i hope thats what you wanna know

Comment: I know that already - I want to know if I can start a PS4 character to play with my friends, and then overwrite later with my 100%ed PS3 character - it's all there in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** it is possible to play on PS4 online and import your PS3 profile later.

> You will be given the option to transfer your previous GTA Online character and progression data, along with the opportunity to change your character’s appearance again. If you wish to **complete the transfer later**, you can return to this option via the Online section of the Pause Menu.

**What will be transferred:**

> - **Money** – Earned in-game money will transfer. Purchased in-game money that has not yet been spent will only transfer within a console
>     family (e.g. PlayStation®3 to PlayStation®4).
> - **Rank and RP** – You will have the same Rank and RP after transfer.
> - **Game Progress** – GTA Online progression will transfer including all unlocks, Contacts, Jobs, Trophies and stats. Items and Property –
>     Weapons/attachments, vehicles/modifications, properties, clothing and
>     all aspects of character appearance will be transferred.
>     Character-owned items (e.g. clothing, weapons, etc.) will remain in
>     the character’s inventory and will not need to be repurchased in-game.
>     Vehicles will appear in the same garage they were left in before the
>     transfer.
> - **Creator** – Jobs made within the Creator will be transferred.
> - **Crews** – Existing Crew information will available.
> - **Achievements and Trophies** – Achievements and trophies will transfer. Additional overall Gamerscore will not be awarded for
>     transferring achievement progress.

Keep in mind that any existing character data and progress will be overwritten and that only money earned will be combined with the imported characters. Also character transfer can only be done once per account.

What you need to do and what else you need to know is described on the [Rockstar support page](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-Transfer-from-Xbox-360-or-PlayStation-3-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-and-PC).

Comment: So I could not transfer PS3 to PS4 and then PC again?

Comment: Can't find an answer for that on the support page sorry. However to make sure you should [**ask a question**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about that

Comment: I suppose I shall just transfer to PC then, as that will be possibly the last game Rockstar shall ever make of Grand Theft Auto.