# Can I transfer a downloaded game from PS3 to PS4?

Tags: ps3, ps4, psn

I recently purchased a PS4, and was told that if I had downloaded GTA V on PS3 (which I did), then it would transfer to my PS4 when I signed in, but I don't see the option to do so anywhere. Can I actually transfer a game from PS3 to PS4?

Comment: In case of GTAV you can transfer your ps3 account but not the game see [**this answer**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225969/can-i-transfer-ps3-profile-if-ive-started-gta-v-online-on-ps4/225983#225983)

Comment: @ExplosionsPlus, at first glance I agree, however I believe OP is intending to ask if the game developer is providing the service for this particular title, as it appears obvious they are misinterpreting the save transfer feature the game offers.

Answer (score 0):

Grand Theft Auto V allows you to **[transfer your save game](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC)**, so that if you were playing on PlayStation 3, you could continue playing the same character on PlayStation 4.

As of current, **there is [no support](http://www.forbes.com/sites/insertcoin/2015/06/18/why-sony-will-never-give-ps4-backward-compatibility/) to play any PlayStation 3 game on PlayStation 4**, and Rockstar have not released any program allowing you free upgrade of your game. This is likely [not going to be a feature they add](http://www.cinemablend.com/games/Xbox-One-Backwards-Compatibility-Surprised-Sony-72571.html), either.