# I have a PS4 and a PS3 and a PS+ account. Can I play GTA V online with the same character on BOTH platforms?

Tags: ps3, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online, psn

I have two houses and I have a PS4 at one house and a PS3 at the other. I want to be able to play GTA V online with the same character and the same progress, is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

No. you can [transfer your online character to your from your PS3 GTA:Online account to your PS4 GTA:Online account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225969/can-i-transfer-ps3-profile-if-ive-started-gta-v-online-on-ps4?rq=1) ***once***. After this they become seperate entities; and progress/cash made on the PS4 version will not transfer back to your PS3 character, and and any progress/cash you make on the PS3 version after the transfer will not be applied to the PS4 account.

The various versions of the game are [not cross-compatible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245063/is-gta-online-cross-platform).